# Get client IP address from JBoss Netty HttpRequest

Tags: jboss, netty

I tried to get a list of headers using HttpRequest.getHeaders(), but i only get a few headers none of which refer to the client's IP address.

Is it possible to get the client's IP using HttpRequest object

Thanks

Comment: Can you lift it from the channel?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a complete example code

```
@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
    InetSocketAddress socketAddress = (InetSocketAddress) ctx.channel().remoteAddress();
    InetAddress inetaddress = socketAddress.getAddress();
    String ipAddress = inetaddress.getHostAddress(); // IP address of client
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the Channel.

```
Channel.getRemoteAddress();
```